# Confused getting a classname to hide a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had this code, that works ok to show/hide a second element by clicking the first one:

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("movs-header");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var x = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the structure (they are repeating elements in a php system):

```
<div id="frm_container_[id]" class="movs-box">
    <div class="movs-header">
        some content here, clickable to show-hide the next sibling div
    </div>
    <div class="movs-body">
        this content will show and hide
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to add this link inside a div with a class="movs-editlink", which has to be outside the movs-box div to refer the id "frm_container", in order to work.

Then the structure will be:

```
<div id="frm_container_[id]" class="movs-box">
    <div class="movs-header">
        some content here, clickable to show-hide the next sibling div
    </div>
    <div class="movs-body">
        this content will show and hide
    </div>
</div>
<div class="movs-editlink">[editlink label="edit" prefix="frm_container_"]</div> <!-- this div to show and hide along -->
```

(please don't mind the shortcode, it works fine)

What I need is to show/hide the last div with the same javascript code (when I click the "movs-header" div, but I fail to refer to "this.className", my guess was:

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("movs-header");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var x = this.nextElementSibling;
        var xedit = this.getElementsByClassName("movs-editlink").classname;
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
            xedit.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
            xedit.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I believe this is not working because the last div is outside the scope of "this", then I think I need to find the NEXT div in the structure with the class "movs-link" to be included in the display toggle, am I right? But I can't find how. Please help.

Comment: there is a function in jQuery  called .closest() 
https://api.jquery.com/closest/
check it out you might get the idea or just use it if you  can

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection, not a single element. You need to loop, or retrieve a specific element by index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your markup, rather than `getElementsByClassName` from `this`, do it with `this.parentNode.nextElementSibling`

```
var xedit = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
```

Or with jquery's [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
var xedit = $(this).parent().nextUntil( "movs-editlink" );
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. it works fine (I'm not so skilled but learning).

It just gives me a problem that is not the solution's fault, but now we're here, please check: when I click the edit link, it performs a jQuery call and pulls a form. Now, if I update the form (clicking the Update button), it keeps working ok. But if I click on Cancel (not doing any action in the form) the javascript stop responding and does not show/hide anymore, and the link stays seen, until I refresh the page. Would you know why?

Comment: @MauricioPraga It is difficult to tell without seeing your code in action. Do you see any errors in browser's console?

Comment: Yes, it says: "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." (it shows jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4). Sorry if I'm not so experienced to handle this and please excuse me if this is not the way to solve it.